# Read data from csv files and set as dynamic properties ignoring null values

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to read data from a csv file and set them as dynamic properties to existing nodes in a Neo4J database. I am using the setProperty procedure because I don't know the data (name and value of the properties). This is my Cypher script:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\Attribute.csv" AS row
MATCH (linkableArtifact:LinkableArtifact {linkableArtifactID: row.linkable_artifact})
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(linkableArtifact, row.attribute_name, row.attribute_value)
YIELD node
RETURN COUNT(node)
```

This works as long `row.attribute_value` is not null. Then I get the following error:

```
Failed to call procedure `apoc.create.setProperty(nodes :: ANY?, key :: STRING?, value :: ANY?) :: (node :: NODE?)`: [null] is not a supported property value
```

Is there a way to check the `row.attribute_value` and then to decide whether to call the procedure or not?

Answer (score 0):

Cipher is a declarative language, so it's easy `row.attribute_value is not NULL`:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\Attribute.csv" AS row
WITH row WHERE row.attribute_value is not NULL
MATCH (artifact:LinkableArtifact {linkableArtifactID: row.linkable_artifact})
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(artifact, 
                             row.attribute_name, 
                             row.attribute_value
)
YIELD node
RETURN COUNT(node)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. It works great and I have learned something new! ;)